# Profit and its value

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a csv entry in this way.

What I need to know: The size of shirt that more profits reported and its value (in money)

---

out

OUT CORRECT

Comment: Please include the error message. At a guess you may want to look at the line `MAYORGANANCIASCAMISETA[precio]++;`

Comment: Please include errors as an edit to your question _as text_, not as animage.

Comment: you can see what I update and what I want to show at the end, @John

Comment: Please follow the rules of the site. Your error message should be included in your question as text.

Comment: And as a stronger hint: look at your `.ContainsKey()` check, and your key in this line of code: `MAYORGANANCIASCAMISETA[precio]++;`

Comment: I know, I ask for the shirt as a key, but the idea is that if it already exists, we add the value of that shirt to the key that already exists

Comment: But you're not adding the value to they key that already exists. You're using `precio` as the key, and trying to add 1 to the price stored in that key, which clearly doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use precio as a key instead of camiseta:

```
if (MAYORGANANCIASCAMISETA.ContainsKey(camiseta))
        {
            // MAYORGANANCIASCAMISETA[precio]++;
            MAYORGANANCIASCAMISETA[camiseta] += precio;
        }
```